# How to split multiple strings that are inside lists?

Tags: python

The context of the issue is me wanting to create a search engine for a list of movies.

```
movies_list=["Avatar", "Planet of the Apes", "Rise of the Apes", "Avatar the Second"]
```

So I want the user to be able to search, for example, `Apes`, and the program will display

```
Planet of the Apes
Rise of the Apes
```

The code I was thinking of trying but I know won't work was

```
movieSearch = movies_list.split()
search = input(str("Search: ")

for movie in movies_list
     if(movieSearch == search):
          print(movie)
     if(movieSearch != search): 
          print("No Match")
```

Mainly because I know the `movieSearch` won't work but I'm just not sure on what else to do

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
flag=0
search = str(input("Search: "))
for movie in movies_list:
    if search in movie:
        flag=1
        print(movie)
if not flag:
    print("no match")
```

Pythonic way:

```
movies_list=["Avatar", "Planet of the Apes", "Rise of the Apes", "Avatar the Second"]
def match_movie(name):
    return [movie for movie in movies_list if name in movie] or 'No Match'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use something like this:

```
>>> search = "Apes"
>>> [i for i in movies_list if search in i.split()]
['Planet of the Apes', 'Rise of the Apes']
```

Do note that this will only search for the exact words and is case sensitive. For example if `search = "apes"` or `search = "APES"`, then the above code would simply generate an empty list.

To make it a case insensitive search you can use [`.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) (or [`.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to convert the string into one of the cases and then compare them.

```
# Convert the `movies_list` to lower case
>>> movies_list = [i.lower() for i in movies_list]

# Convert `search` to lower case and then compare
>>> [i for i in movies_list if search.lower() in i.split()]
```

**EDIT:** `i.split()` will give an exact word search result. If you want a partial search then simply use `i`.

```
[i for i in movies_list if search in i]
```

Comment: @Hackaholic - Thanks for the correction. +1 for your answer. :)

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro there is a slight problem with this, if i search `ar` for example, `Avatar` still appears as a result because of the `ar` at the end of it

Comment: @LiamEmery - Then instead of `search in i` use `search in i.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in simple steps.

```
In [21]: movies_list=["Avatar", "Planet of the Apes", "Rise of the Apes", "Avatar the Second"]
In [25]: search = 'Apes'    
In [22]: [i for i in movies_list if search in i]
Out[22]: ['Planet of the Apes', 'Rise of the Apes']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print('\n'.join(x for x in movies_list if search in x) or 'No results')
```